# Capture Screen But Not Current Form In C#?

Tags: c#, screen-capture

I want to capture the screen but without the current form, I tried to minimize -> capture -> maximize, but I'm looking for a better solution if exists. This was my code::

```
    int w = this.Width;
    int h = this.Height;
    Size sz = this.Size;
    Point loc = this.Location;

    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;

    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);

    using (Bitmap b = new Bitmap(w, h))
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b))
        {
            g.CopyFromScreen(loc, new Point(0, 0), sz);
        }

        b.Save(Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\\slides\\screen.jpeg");

        this.BackgroundImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(@"slides\screen.jpeg");
    }

    this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
```

And I ask if there is a direct way to put the captured image as form background, without saving it.

Comment: Just set the form's Opacity to 99 in the designer and you don't have to hide it.  Not a feature, it's a bug.

Comment: @Hans that's what i was doing and happy with (Opacity <100) on Vista, until i tested on Win 7; There my form on top always got captured (not what i want, want to capture what's underneath my form without hiding it - Any ideas?

Comment: Never mind, i worked it out. Had to do with Aero being enabled on the Win 7 PC; Moral of the story: Disable Aero when taking screenshots (Aero = useless feature)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try, although I did notice both yours and mine is marginally offset by the form border.

```
    int w = this.Width; 
    int h = this.Height; 
    Size sz = this.Size; 
    Point loc = this.Location; 
    Hide();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
    using (Image b = new Bitmap(w, h)) 
    { using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(b)) 
    { 
        g.CopyFromScreen(loc, new Point(0, 0), sz); }

        Image x = new Bitmap(b);
        this.BackgroundImage = x;
    } 
    Show();
```

Comment: You ought to document why 500 is a special number.  Is it better than 314?

Comment: I believe hes using 500 to ensure sufficent time for an ainmations to have taken place, as I tried it without and got the form, 100 showed it dimming..

Answer (score 4):

1. Set the forms [`Opacity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.opacity.aspx) to 0.

   This will make the form completely transparent and hence invisible.
2. Make the form invisible. Set the [`Visible`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visible.aspx) property to `false.

   This will hide the form without changing it's state, though on XP this won't make the window disappear straight away.

Comment: Just set it to 99 so it isn't invisible :)  Setting Visible to false doesn't actually work, you still see it on XP.  Until all other overlapped windows have caught up with their painting.